# Cannot execute multiple update queries in one statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

I want to update multiple rows in one statement. I am using CodeIgniter framework. My code is given below.

```
$query = "update students set id = 12 where id = 10; update students set id = 13 where id = 11;";
$this->db->query($query);
```

But it is giving me error, saying I have a syntax error near 'update students set id = 13 where id = 11;' I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use codeigniter Active record batch update :

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'My date 2'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'Another date 2'
   )
);

$this->db->update_batch('mytable', $data, 'title');
```

Answer (score 3):

use batch query for this

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'My date 2'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'Another date 2'
   )
);

$this->db->update_batch('mytable', $data, 'title');

// Produces:
// UPDATE `mytable` SET `name` = CASE
// WHEN `title` = 'My title' THEN 'My Name 2'
// WHEN `title` = 'Another title' THEN 'Another Name 2'
// ELSE `name` END,
// `date` = CASE
// WHEN `title` = 'My title' THEN 'My date 2'
// WHEN `title` = 'Another title' THEN 'Another date 2'
// ELSE `date` END
// WHERE `title` IN ('My title','Another title')
```

for more info :- https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html#update

Answer (score 2):

the problem, quite likely, is that mysql_query only handles one query at a time.
https://www.php.net/mysql_query

Answer (score 1):

Mysql_query() function can handle only one query at a time.  So you can use

```
$this->db->update_batch('table_name', $data_array, 'unique_field');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about mysql, then you can use [mysqli::multi_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) . This is basically used to executes one or multiple queries which are concatenated by a semicolon.